# How to use nested case classes and spray json implicits

Tags: json, scala, spray

I am trying to convert case classes to `json` with spray.io json.  The code below:

```
case class Value(amt: Int)
case class Item(name: String, count: Value)
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val itemFormat = jsonFormat2(Item)
}
import MyJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._
val json = Item("mary", Value(2)).toJson
println(json)
```

gives:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type onextent.bluecase.examples.ex1.ExampleJson2.MyJsonProtocol.JF[Value]
```

I've tried to define a `JsonProtocol` for Value as well but get same.  Searching stackoverflow I only see this error related to `generics`, which this is not.

What am I missing?  (re-reading about implicits now...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a json format for your Value class as it is part of your Item class. So your object would need to look like this:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
 implicit val valueFormat = jsonFormat1(Value)
 implicit val itemFormat = jsonFormat2(Item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer mentioned by StuartMcvean is correct. However I just want to add a note that the order in which you declare the implicits is important. For example the below declaration will still result in the same failure.

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
 implicit val itemFormat = jsonFormat2(Item)
 implicit val valueFormat = jsonFormat1(Value)
}
```